# iOS: Update marketing url in App Store Connect without uploading new build

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to update **marketing url** without uploading new build in app store ?

Comment: No, meta data is reviewed at the same time your app is reviewed. Yo change meta data you need to release a new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unfortunately is Impossible! the only thing you could change without a new build is the promotional text.