# update Marketing URL in app store connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Hello my app just approved on app store so how can I change/update marketing URL in app store connect?

I am trying to click on it but not selecting

Comment: Did you do any kind of research? Does this help? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125605

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: Update marketing url in App Store Connect without uploading new build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789230/ios-update-marketing-url-in-app-store-connect-without-uploading-new-build)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.